# Prove VIF of jth predictor is jth diagonal entry of inverse of correlation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, regression, covariance, variance

I am trying to prove that the variance inflation factor for the jth predictor variable in a centered/scaled regression model is the jth diagonal entry of the inverse of the correlation matrix of the predictors.
The first idea I had was to try $VIF_j=\frac{Var({\hat{\beta_j}})}{\sigma^2}$, where $\hat{\beta_j}$ is the estimator for the regression coefficient of the jth predictor. But I do not know how to get from here to the diagonal entry I want.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that in OLS,
$$
\text{Var}(\hat{\beta}|X)=\sigma^2(X'X)^{-1},
$$
hence, 
$$
\frac{\text{Var}(\hat{\beta_j})}{\sigma^2} = \frac{\sigma^2(X'X)^{-1}_{jj}}{\sigma^2} = (X'X)^{-1}_{jj}
$$

Comment: Is that last term the jth diagonal entry of the inverse of the correlation matrix? I don't recall X'X being that matrix.

Comment: For centered data, $X'X$ is the covaraince matrix where the diagonal is the variance of the $j$th predictor.